# Adding image to every page of a letter created with scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2, eso-pic

I created a letter using `scrlttr2` package from KOMA-Script. I'd like to add an image at the bottom of each of its pages. Here is what I have for this purpose:

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{
         \hspace*{1.5in}\includegraphics{Logo_unten.eps}
    }
}
```

which works, but if I print the result, the half of the image will be cut off. So, how can I elevate the image something like 1 cm?

Comment: `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{
         \raisebox{1cm}{\hspace*{1.5in}\includegraphics{Logo_unten.eps}}
    }
}`

Comment: Your code *should* place the image on the baseline, which should be at the lower left of the page. As such, the entire image should be visible. If this is not the case (as you state, "half of the image [is] cut off"), then the image must have a different bounding box, or you're doing something completely different to what you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you give us not an compilable example of your letter but only a code snippet I have to guess what you are doing :-(

> Please next question add an complete, short and compilable example
>   that we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Because you added not your image `Logo_unten.eps` I used instead image `example-image` from package `mwe`. Please see that the size of this image may differ to yours so I had to add the option `width=2cm` to avoid overlapping text of the letter ...

To simply move the image 1 cm higher you can use command `\raisebox` ...

Please see the following compiling code

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4, 
  backaddress=off,
  foldmarks=false,
  parskip=half,
  addrfield=false,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel} % <=========================================

\let\raggedsignature\raggedright

\setkomavar{fromname}{john doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{street number\\ plz place}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+43 1234 567890}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{jdoe@posteo.net}
\setkomavar{place}{place}
%\setkomavar{signature}{john doe\\trainer}

\renewcaptionname{english}\emailname{\Letter}% orig: \Email <===========
\renewcaptionname{english}\phonename{\Mobilefone}% orig: \Telefon <=====

\usepackage{blindtext}% <============================= to get dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% <============ to visualize text area and margins
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \raisebox{1cm}{% <========================= shift image 1cm higher
         \hspace*{1.5in}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
      }
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company\\Address\\City}

\setkomavar{subject}{Position Title}
\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
Content goes here.

\Blindtext

\closing{Sincerely yours,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 2):

You can load package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. Then you can declare a new layer for the image and add this layer to every pagestyle (including `empty`):

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  align=bl,
  hoffset=1.5in,
  voffset=\paperheight,
  addvoffset=-.3in,% <- adjust this value to your needs
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLL{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
]{letterimage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{letterimage}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}

\usepackage{lipsum}% <- only for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  align=bl,
  hoffset=1.5in,
  voffset=\paperheight,
  addvoffset=-.3in,% <- adjust this value to your needs
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLL{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
]{letterimage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{letterimage}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient\\Address}
\opening{Hallo,}
\lipsum[1-10]
\closing{Best regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]